# TypeScript default function for higher-order function generic type

Tags: typescript, types, higher-order-functions

I have a higher-order function which correctly infers the type of its returned function based on a generic function passed as an argument, might be easier to understand with a simple example:

```
function someFunction<T>(f: (s: string) => T) {
  return function(s: string): T {
    return f(s)
  }
}
```

So, if I pass a function that returns a `string`, the returned function will correctly infer the type:

```
const funcStr = someFunction((s: string) => s)
//    ^ const funcStr: (s: string) => string
```

And if I pass a function that returns a `number` it will return a function that in turn returns a number:

```
const funcNum = someFunction((s: string) => Number(s))
//    ^ const funcStr: (s: string) => number
```

Now I want to add a default value to the higher-order function, but haven't been able to make it work:

```
// Type '(s: string) => number' is not assignable to type '(s: string) => T'.
function someFunction<T>(f: (s: string) => T = (s: string) => Number(s)) {
//                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  return function(s: string): T {
    return f(s)
  }
}
```

How can I add a default function to the higher-order function and still make it infer the type if another function is used?

[Working TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgWwKYDFzXmAHgBUA+ACmAC5EzlrkoAnGMAcwEpEBeExIzgN4BYAFCJEjDFBCMkoSLAS16TFh2pFEwseIlSZc2u1HiAvqPMjREBA0TAAciDTcU6bLkVgyylKracPIhOaABGGIxGxiI2YHbAAMpMrqiYOAr4PnR+zAHcvMjRogD0xYgAEnAA7ogQAIZIAJKIdcjIMKxIdYgAJhjAdSAANlD2nviIVTBQABZwIKOhknUA1mqIsxiIrBhgETAQLYysAPwlxedjGQhuaeMIxORUNNkMuRz5fK6+b2qBvCFwpFCoJLuJJNJZFc8EpXv51F9tKVdOD9FDgEYwYhLMicRcRMjYvEQil3OkYd5ooTbKNEskuLcPNdvD94f8UEUREA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking the compiler is right to complain.  You can always use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress the error on the default function parameter, as well as providing a [default *type* parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) for `T` so the compiler knows what to do if it can't infer `T` from the argument:

```
function someFunction<T = number>(
  f: (s: string) => T = ((s: string) => Number(s)) as any
) {
  return function (s: string): T {
    return f(s)
  }
}
```

And this will behave exactly as you want:

```
const fNum = someFunction()
console.log(fNum("3.14159").toFixed(2)); // 3.14
const fStr = someFunction((s: string) => s)
```

But the problem with this approach is that the type parameter `T` is specified by the *caller* of `someFunction()`, not by the implementation.  And so nothing will prevent a malicious and/or confused caller from doing something like this:

```
const fOops = someFunction<string>();
```

The caller has specified that `T` is a `string`, and even though `T`'s default is `number`, it has been overridden by an explicit `string` type.   So the compiler thinks that `fOops` is of type `(s: string) => string`, but of course at runtime we know it won't be:

```
try {
  fOops("oopsie").toUpperCase(); // no compiler error
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e); // fOops(...).toUpperCase is not a function
}
```

And that's why the compiler complains; it is saying that it can't be sure that the default value of `f` will be of a type appropriate for the `T` specified by the caller.

If you don't care about this possibility, then this approach is fine and requires the minimum change to your code.

---

If you want to prevent the possibility of an `fOops`-like situation, you could change `someFunction()` to be an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to have two call signatures:

```
// call signatures
function someFunction(): (s: string) => number;
function someFunction<T>(f: (s: string) => T): (s: string) => T;
```

If you call `someFunction()` with no argument, then you are invoking the first call signature, and the return type must be `(s: string) => number`; there's no generic type parameter on this call signature at all.

Otherwise, if you call it with a callback argument, then you are invoking the second call signature; there's a type parameter `T` corresponding to the return type of that callback.

Then the implementation can be similar to before, but you loosen the types up to prevent a complaint (here we will just use `any` as the return type):

```
function someFunction(f: (s: string) => any = (s: string) => Number(s)) {
  return function (s: string) {
    return f(s)
  }
}
```

Now the calls you intend to support still work:

```
const fNum = someFunction()
console.log(fNum("3.14159").toFixed(2)); // 3.14

const fStr = someFunction((s: string) => s)
```

but it is impossible to invoke the zero-arg call signature with a type parameter, so you can't call it the wrong way anymore:

```
const fOops = someFunction<string>() // error!
// Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBJKiSwLICCUUEATgC4BCArowKIAmA5hAMIg6eIkRIkAZq2DxGASwD2wJFAWQAYtNmLgAHgAqSALylWYAEYMAfAAoJALiQ2ojqI3pzgPAJTGrSQxMbZ1d3Tx8-JAA5M0t6Z29fISQQYABPXwJicRJ6CEZWemUpGXklJxcVMK9vR0MsnJy8gqKkCQSxRoBfTpIe7JJ4JTc2mLBjFTUITVKdG29epCHgVQwIADoMBR47MZsAIgBmdYBGABYTgFYATn3vdcYFdTkADwguGwAmRIBuJAB6f5IY7nRbLEYSADK7gmqg0WjKwGClTcHhqkSgC0IYOGjDaAHkFDAoLCpjNtEpdKjwrYsTl3GkRANxBJCcSDgoiVA5BA7g8FABVGAwBiCOjzRZdJYgRjwAAWTggmUWg2GCjWm22NiVf0BBK5NnWRvujyFIvoYuQchJwAUeJAbQROklomy-VdJDI0DgiCQ+IAbgwtiAuO8mTkShTlHDpk6lPNHCEqmiIkZ-MBYgwfotI4jJvDZpT9LYHBVQinfGmArUy8nwpX-Pps8zczp87HC0jS0nqeiq6lGUEUdVU-4xnEEsrmbl8oVinHlD2R1PGuJmnO2h1p0h+jl3czwXiJGNSQWoxKD2qNVsdsezAcQRcbnzHs83h9vt5dUDHx7xIe2mhehTw7c8lwrDEsRxFYjzZEkTBjclESpEdaQBIEGHoBR6AAQkWPUOBeEVZDDE4UnoHgzAgYBGCgAAaJBzHYJAeDtJAAAZ1ldTp+i6IA)